# failed to load ldlinux.32 in windows

Tags: 18.04, usb-installation, rufus

i am using dell inspirion 1545(3gb RAM) with windows 7 . i want to install ubuntu along with windows 7 ,i made my usb bootable using rufus tool but when i try to install it gives an error **Failed to load ldlinux**.

Comment: What OS/release?   You've tagged 14.04 because that's your release, or is it something else?  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016

Comment: its 18.04 and 17.04

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 (from 2017-April) was a standard release with 9 months of supported life now well since gone, it release-upgraded to 17.10 also now EOL so it's upgrade path too is gone.  You don't want to use 17.04 except for off-line historical reasons.  Did you verify your ISO after download (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then write to install media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any media used, cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/..)

Comment: sir i download ubuntu 18.04 and used rufus tool to make my pendrive bootable after that when i try to install it it gives an error i.e faled to load ldlinux.32

Comment: Yes, as asked - did you verify the download was bit perfect?  (ie. verified the checksum) then verify the install media (using "*Check disk for defects*" option).  If the write to media or media itself is badly flawed you can get to condition you have, where I usually test booting it (and run "*Check disk for defects*")  on another box; if it fails on second box it'll be 99% guaranteed it was bad ISO or bad write to media (assuming good media). My prior comments are on steps needed to be write before boot will work.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-verify-your-ubuntu-download/14010

Comment: What version of rufus did you use? Not all versions support ubuntu 18.04 and version 19.

Comment: sir i used rufus 3.9